# Entity Framework newbie question. I select a table from the wizard, but nothing shows up

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I create a new .edmx and the wizard allows me to choose the tables I want to expose after I pick my connection. I pick one table, and nothing shows on the design surface. The model explorer opens but nothing seems to have happened. Any ideas what's going here? There is a message on the design surface that says use the toolbox. I can drag items on but I don't seem to be getting the experience I've had in the past with LinqToSql. Am I doing something wrong? In SSMS, I seem to have all the rights I need using Windows Auth. Any ideas what I can try to correct this? happy Friday and thanks for any tips.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Error List window for messages.

One common problem is if the table doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: I think you're correct. I didn't see any output message, but I'm able to drag other tables on there and they are showing up. What can you do for tables with no PK?

Comment: Entity Framework was designed to work with "entities", which require a primary key to identify them. You'd have to add a PK to the table for it to work with EF.